# Database not updating with loop

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have to distribute customers to different employees based on percentages inputted by the user. For example, I have 10 customers that belong to salesman3 and I input 50% for salesman1 and 50% for salesman2. That means 5 of those customers go to salesman1 and the other 5 to salesman2. I want to do this by just updating the salesman ID in the database. I have put in some counters to make sure that it is getting the percentages entered and that it is looping through the entire list of salesmen. It proves that it is running through the entire foreach loop and is getting the percentages, but when I check the database it only updates it one time. Here is the code that I have. I'm sorry in advance if I don't have something right here. I'm a new user and a beginner coder. Thanks.

```
public ActionResult Submit(string json, string terminated_id, string total_clients)
{
    int T_ID = Convert.ToInt32(terminated_id);
    int T_clients = Convert.ToInt32(total_clients);
    List<emp_info> list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<emp_info>>(json);
    int counter = 0;
    foreach (var obj in list)
    {
        counter++;
    }
    int counting = 0;
    string[] array = new string[counter];
    int i = 0;
    foreach (var obj in list)
    {
        counting++;
        array[i] = obj.percent;
        i++;
        if (obj.percent != "")
        {
            int count = Convert.ToInt32((double)T_clients * (Convert.ToDouble(obj.percent) / 100));
            var selected_list = db.Clients.ToList().Take(count);
            var query = from cust in selected_list
                        where cust.Salesperson_ID == T_ID
                        select cust;
            foreach (Client cust in query)
            {
              int int_id =  Convert.ToInt32(obj.ID);
                cust.Salesperson_ID = int_id;
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            //db.SaveChanges();
            //return View();
        }
    }
    ViewBag.counting = counting;
    ViewBag.percentages = array;
    ViewBag.counter = counter;
    db.SaveChanges();
    return View();
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by _only updates it one time_?

Comment: Like if I have to distribute 10 customers that belong to salesperson3 and if I put 50% for salesperson 1 and 50% for salesperson2 then it will only update the first 5 customers to salesperson1 and the other 5 will just remain assigned to salesperson3.

Comment: How many objects are there in 'list' when debugging?

Comment: But if the value of `count` is `5`, then only those 5 will be updated (not 10).

Comment: 'list' is just the list of employees. The number of objects in there is dependent on how many employees are in the database.

Comment: Yes the value of count would be 5 because of the 50%. I'm confused on how to get the other 50% reassigned to a different ID.

Comment: Like you send these 5 you also need to send other 5

Comment: You have some awful code here, and it can all be done in less that half of what you have shown. No time know, but I will add an answer in an hour or so. And start by changing `(string json, string terminated_id, string total_clients)` to `(List<emp_info> json, int terminated_id, int total_clients)` and remove the first 3 line of code. And to get `counter`, use `int counter = json.Count;`. But all this suggest you have other problems with your view and they way your sending the data to the controller.

Comment: Looping to update rows in a table is generally a bad idea. Have you considered trying to do this in SQL instead? I.e. as a single `UPDATE` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Simplify your API, by actually taking what you want them to be rather than generic json and strings and then converting them.

1. Grab all the records you are going to update in one database call.
2. Create a new array that contains the ID and the upperbound of
   percent (aggregated) that is theirs. {{Name="Bob",ID=1,percent=5},{Name="John",ID=2,percent=10},{Name="Joe",ID=3,percent=85}} becomes {{ID=1,percent=5},{ID=2,percent=15},{ID=3,percent=100}}
3. Loop through the array and
   assign the correct salesperson.
4. Update database.

Like this:

```
public ActionResult Submit(List<emp_info> list, int terminated_id)
{
  // Grab records to update in one call
  var clients=db.Clients.Where(c=>c.Salesperson_ID==terminated_id).ToList();
  var total=clients.Count();

  if (clients.Sum(c=>c.percent)!=100)
    throw new ApplicationException("Percentages must add up to 100%!");

  // Create new array with upperbound percent
  var newlist=list
    .Aggregate(new {ID=0,percent=0},(prev,curr)=>new {
      ID=curr.ID,percent=prev.percent+curr.percent
    });
  // Sanity check
  Debug.Assert(newlist.Last().percent==100);

  // Loop through records and assign new salesperson
  for(var x=0;x<total;x++)
  {
    clients[x].Salesperson_ID=newlist.Last(l=>l.percent<=x*100/total).ID;
  }

  // Send updates to database
  db.SaveChanges();
  ViewBag.counting = total;
  ViewBag.percentages = list.Select(l=>l.percent).ToArray();
  ViewBag.counter = total;
  return View();
}
```

Comment: You can also do it via join, but that's a bit more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

You are always taking first count clients with this `db.Clients.ToList().Take(count);`
Try `var selected_list = db.Clients.ToList().Skip((counting-1) * count).Take(count);`
(counting-1) starts with 0 so in the beginning there won't be any skipping of clients, and for the next employee you will skip the first 5 clients (in you case). The code is not tested but give it a try. I wanted to comment but I don't have enough rep :)